# Deleting log files from an AWS RDS Postgres instance

Tags: postgresql, log-files, amazon-rds

How can I delete logs from an RDS Postgres instance? I just noticed that my instance is displaying the message, `storage-full`. I can find any descriptions of how to deleted the log files, which I think are the reason that the storage is full. The data in the database is in the ~50MB range.

This is the message that I see on the RDS dashboard when I am logged into AWS:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is controlled through the use of "Parameter Group" settings.

1) In the RDS dashboard, go to "Parameter Groups"

2) Create a new parameter group, make sure the "Group Family" is set to postgres9.3, name it whatever

3) Go back to "Parameter Groups", select the newly created group and then "Edit Parameters"

4) Set "rds.log_retention_period" to whatever value you'd like, default is 4320 minutes (72 hours).

5) Save the changes, and wait for the changes to be synced.

Also be sure to modify your log settings if your concerned with the size, this can drastically alter the size of the log files and hence your storage space.

Relevant link [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.PostgreSQL.html)

Comment: More about this from Amazon: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-logs/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. Once you get to a `storage-full` state, AWS no longer allows modifying the parameter group.